# VBA html reader with delay

Tags: vba, html

Working on a html reader for a webpage, the problem is: The webpage got a loading screen. Any way to do this without using Internet Explorer application ?.

```
While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

Do Until IE.statusText = "Done"
    DoEvents
Loop

Do Until IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
```

I would perfer to use something like this reader.

```
Function GetHTML(URL As String) As String
    Dim HTML As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        GetHTML = .responseText
    End With

End Function
```

Any ideas or leads will be most appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to delay your code until the loading screen disappears?